# Displaying carousel indicators when using react-swipe

Tags: reactjs, meteor, swipe

I'm having trouble having my cake and eating it too.

If I use a [react-bootstrap carousel](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#carousels) then it doesn't handle swipe on mobile but I get next/previous buttons and the carousel indicators to show the user what element of the carousel they are on.

If I use [react-swipe](https://github.com/voronianski/react-swipe) then I get swiping but none of the other carousel features.

My component so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import ReactSwipe from 'react-swipe';

const Index = () => (
  <div className="foo">
    <ReactSwipe className="carousel" key={3}>
      <div>first panel</div>
      <div>second panel</div>
      <div>third panel</div>
    </ReactSwipe>
  </div>      
);

export default Index;
```

How do I go about getting the carousel state and turning that into a set of indicators, one of which is *active*?

Comment: have you checked this https://github.com/voronianski/swipe-js-iso#config-options ? it gives you the option for the callback with the index value so you can know the state to set to the indicators. The number of indicators can be controlled by your side

Comment: I saw that but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get to that API from a react component.